# Design pattern to ensure data initialization for many classes

Tags: design-patterns, initialization

I am creating a tower defense game. Before a level is created I need to have statistics about monsters, towers etc. ready in memory. For example:

```
fastmonster.name = "Rabbit";
fastmonster.health = 100;
fastmonster.speed = 10;
slowmonster.name = "Turtle";
slowmonster.health = 500;
slowmonster.speed = 2;
```

The same goes for towers and other stuff.

(I haven't decided on how this will be read from files in detail.)

How do I ensure that all this data is ready before objects of monster or tower classes are created? I am looking for a design pattern that would allow me to initialize all data globally once and allow me to create monster objects with the regular constructor. At the same time it should make sure that no objects are created before the unit statistics have been read.

I am sure this problem has been solved a million times but so far I failed to find any solution that really fits this problem and is not a super complex with several abstract levels.

**My solution so far**

I made the constructor private and defined a `create()` function that looks like this

```
Monster Monster::create (MonsterType type) {
    if (!initialized()) {
        initialize();
        initialized = true;
    }
    return new Monster(type);
}
```

The problem is now that I would need to create the same function for towers and all other game elements. This seems like a lot of duplication.

**Another thought**

I keep all the constructors private. Create a (singleton?) factory class and make it a friend of all the classes and let it create all the objects. The Factory would make the initialization when it is created.

**GOF Patterns**

I looked at other creational patterns but none of them seem to fit. Or I just didn't understand them enough.

Comment: The language is C++, I assume?

Comment: Yes, C++ with Qt. But I intentionally left it out assuming the solution would be language agnostic.

Comment: I would go for a factory and do a data driven creation to make it generic (and avoid writing specific code for each class you introduce).

Comment: What is "data driven creation"?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is great.

You can improve it by using **Template Method** GOF pattern, in order to avoid duplication.

Unfortunately I don't know how it implement in c++, but in c# it could be the following:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T>
{
    private bool initialized = false;

    public BaseEntity<T> Create(T typeOfEntity)
    {
        if (!Initialized())
        {
            Initialize();
            initialized = true;
        }

        return GetEntity(typeOfEntity);
    }

    protected abstract void Initialize();
    protected abstract bool Initialized();
    protected abstract BaseEntity<T> GetEntity(T typeOfEntity);
}

public class MonsterEntity:BaseEntity<MonsterType>
{
    //...

    public MonsterEntity(MonsterType typeOfEntity)
    {
        //...
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        //initialize logic
    }

    protected override bool Initialized()
    {
        bool initialized = false;

        //check for initialization

        return initialized;
    }

    protected override BaseEntity<MonsterType> GetEntity(MonsterType typeOfEntity)
    {
        return new MonsterEntity(typeOfEntity);
    }

    //...
}
```

Also you can add subclasses for your entites and make method `GetEntity` the Fabric Method.